# Split up string of arrays in Typescript

Tags: javascript

I am currently getting a string of arrays which hold values.

At the moment the values are all wrapped together, but I want each value to be on it's own line. At the moment I am simply returning the value of the array of strings through mapping such as

```
return supplierRepository.allSuppliers.map((suppliers: ISupplier) => {
    suppliers.name.replace("","<br />")

    console.log(suppliers.name)

    return suppliers.name
  })
```

How do I split this? [In this image, 'thing' should be on a new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrFbC.png)

I then want every object to be a clickable object in the list

Comment: And  where's typescript or reactjs here? Where's any code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to split out "thing" from your string in the way you want.

Javascript isn't clever enough to intuit where you want the string to be split; you need to tell it some rule or other which instructs it where to split.

If it is always the string `"thing"` which is appended to your `supplier.name`, you could use the length of `"thing"` to split at that point with a piece of code like this:

```
let supplierName = "ZZ Trinity Merchantsthing"; // This is your string to have <br> inserted
let appendedString = "thing"; // This is the string you want to split into a new line
let brInsertPos = appendedString.length - supplierName.length; // This calculates where to insert the <br> tag

// These lines insert the tag where we worked out it should go
let resultString = supplierName.substr(0, brInsertPos);
resultString += "<br>";
resultString += supplierName.substr(brInsertPos);
```